# How to implement in Rails "Showing 11 of 20 of 100 entries" paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I have this table in rails which has a lot of data. I have already implemented using kaminari paginate

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="pull-right right-paginate"><%= paginate @applications %></div>
  </div>
```

but i want to be able to do something like this "showing x to y of z entries" whereby in page 1 it says 'Showing 1 to 10 of 80 entries' and in page 2 it says "Showing 11 to 20 of 80 entries"

How is the best way to implement this is in rails using kaminari or any other gems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaminari has a helper method [`page_entries_info`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/amatsuda/kaminari/Kaminari/ActionViewExtension:page_entries_info) that will give you what you need.  You can tweak the message by passing in options, or change it completely by modifying the corresponding entry in your locale file.  The default locale configuration can be seen [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/config/locales/kaminari.yml) - you may override them in your own locale config as you see fit.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, use gem

```
 gem "will_paginate", '~> 3.0'
```

In the controller for example

```
def index
  @documents = Document.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'created_at DESC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @documents }
  end
end
```

And at the end in the index.html.erb add this:

```
 <%= will_paginate(@movies, :renderer => 'BootstrapPaginationHelper::LinkRenderer') %>
```